# Save custom created objects via sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I still struggling how can I create and store particular size of objects in sequelize.

**Here is my code:**

```
var pointsize = req.body.pointsize;

Point.bulkCreate([{ pointname: req.body.point }]).success(function() {});
```

I wanna store pointsize count of rows in Point table. Thanks for any advise guys!

**Edited:**

```
 function makeArrayOf(value, length) {
   var arr = [], i = length;
   while (i--) {
     arr[i] = value + (i+1);
   }
   return arr;
 }
 var pointsize = req.body.pointsize;

 Point.bulkCreate([makeArrayOf('Point Name', pointsize)]).success(function() { });
```

something like this... This create me `pointsize` rows in db (As I wish). But I don't know how to store name of point into database.

So if pointsize = 5 then rows in database will looks like:

```
id |   name  | ownerid
---------------------
1  | Point 1 | 101
2  | Point 2 | 101
3  | Point 3 | 101
4  | Point 4 | 101
5  | Point 5 | 101
```

Comment: Does the Point model have a pointsize column? In that case it should be as simple as adding pointsize: whatever count you want when creating. Otherwise, please explain more thoroughly what you wish to do - show tables or model definitions

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Thanks for help! I have edited code please take a look.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do? What exactly do you want a row in your table to look like? 
If you simply wish to insert a row with to columns, you can do bulkCreate([{ name: 'sometihng', pointsize: 42 }]).

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Pointsize is value from my form (If somebody will add number 10 then post function will create 10 rows in point table with names Point1,Point2,Point3,Point4....Point10).

Comment: @JanAagaardMeier Please take a look, now it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function makeArrayOf(value, length) {
   var arr = [], i = length;
   while (i--) {
     arr[i] = { name: value + (i+1) };
   }
   return arr;
}
var pointsize = req.body.pointsize;

Point.bulkCreate(makeArrayOf('Point Name', pointsize)).success(function() { });
```

Notice how the value has been wrapped in an object, and I removed the array aroud the return value of `makeArrayOf`.

Each element in the arrray will be an object, with a property name:

```
Point.bulkCreate([{ name:'..' }, {name: '..'}, ...]).success(function() { });
```

Comment: BTW, what is different between `success` and `then`? Sequelize documentation uses `then`, but I found the `success` usage every now and then. What is the correct and format one?

Comment: With v 2.0 sequelize switched from eventemitters to promises. success is event emitter style, then is promise style